# How to use interpolation on property bindings for ng-container?

Tags: angular

I am using a structural directive with an ng-container. I need to set a property value (which is a boolean, in my case) for a property associated with the structural directive. Without interpolating the boolean value, I'd do it in the following way:

```
<ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: false}">
        Something here...
</ng-container>
```

My question is, how can I set the hidden or any other property using interpolation? Something like this...

```
<clr-dg-column *ngFor="let item of headers">
  <ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: {{item.hidden}}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </ng-container>
</clr-dg-column>
```

I am trying to automate the population of the headers as an object which is defined as follows:-

```
headers = [
{
  'name':'col1',
  'hidden':'false'
},
{
  'name':'Name',
  'hidden':'false'
},
{
  'name':'col3',
  'hidden':'false'
}
```

]

Comment: just don't use interpolation, it should work like this `<ng-container *clrDgHideableColumn="{hidden: item.hidden}">`

Comment: Thank you for that. I tried that and it seems to work. But for some reason, I was not getting the desired result. Till I realized the hidden property was being set as a string instead of a boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maximus

Thank you for the answer.

The generalized answer to my question is:

```
<ng-container *structuralDirective="{property: key.property}">
```

The reason I was not getting the intended result even with this implementation was because I was setting the 'hidden' property as a string ('true' is a string value) instead of setting it as a boolean, which was expected by the set function in my structural directive.